# sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccesorImpl.- error en Java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en **Java** con conexión a base de datos en **MySQL**. Todas las funciones de la aplicación funciona correctamente pero mientras uso la aplicación (transcurridos 2-3 minutos en la aplicación) se me abre una **ventana emergente** y entonces la aplicación se pone en segundo plano.

Estoy utilizando **JDK 1.8**. `java -version`

```
C:\Users\omaza>java -version
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)
```

Utilizando Netbeans IDE 8.2 y el Driver para la conexión a base de datos MySQL es:

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar.
```

**Código de conexión a la base de datos:**

```
public class Conexiones {
    static String bbdd = "agenda";
    static String login = "root";
    static String password = "";
    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static Connection c = null;

/**
 * Conexión a BBDD.
 *
 * @param bbdd
 * @return
 */
public static Connection conexion_a_BBDD(String bbdd) {
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(url + bbdd, login, password);
        return c;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getStackTrace(), "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException n) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡MySQL failed! Se cerrará el programa...", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        n.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

**¿A qué se debe este error?** No encuentro ninguna solución en Stackoverflow.

Ver imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes añadir el código y la configuración para saber como te estás conectando?

Comment: @dgrana Pregunta editada añadiendo la información y código.

Comment: Cuando abres una conexión nueva, la cierras después de usarla? Si reutilizas la misma sesión después de un rato puede que esté caducada y entonces te salta el error

Comment: Sí, en las todas funciones donde creo una variable "c" de Conexiones para conectar a la base de datos, seguidamente después de las consultas, cierro. Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);   y para cerrarla: c.close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías cambiar tu variable `Connection` para que no fuese `static`

```
 Connection c = null;
```

Dicha variable en `static` hará que cada vez que se llame al método de conexión de `BBDD` devolverá un valor actualizado para la única instancia que tienes.

También quitaría la siguiente linea, no es necesaria:

```
Class.forName(driver);
```

Tu código quedaría de esta manera:

```
public class Conexiones {
static String bbdd = "agenda";
static String login = "root";
static String password = "";
static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
//static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
Connection c = null;

/**
 * Conexión a BBDD.
 *
 * @param bbdd
 * @return
 */
public static Connection conexion_a_BBDD(String bbdd) {
    try {
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(url + bbdd, login, password);
        return c;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getStackTrace(), "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException n) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡MySQL failed! Se cerrará el programa...", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        n.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

Prueba de esta manera y coméntanos si surge al cambio.

Comment: Sí, lo he medio conseguido con esos cambios, Tuve que quitar también la excepción del Cass.forName (ClassNotFoundException). Digo medio conseguido porque creo que el fallo viene cuando se pierde en algún momento la conexión con el servidor Xampp o MySQL y entonces el programa se bloquea. ¿Existe alguna posibilidad de controlar eso y mostrar un mensaje de alerta cuando se bloquee o salte el warning?